# How to add constant text in editText box?

Tags: android, android-edittext, radio-button, radio-group

There are three radio button:
1. NID 2. Passport 3. Driving Licence

After that there is a edit text box where user write the ID which they already selected. If user select NID, NID- will be showed in editText box which is not removable, then the user can write 12345678 in editText box, it will be saved in database like NID-12345678. Here is my code:

1. Radio Button action:

   ```
   public void RadioButtonClicked(View view) {


   String selectedID = "";
   boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

   switch (view.getId()) {
       case R.id.uNid:
           if (checked)
               selectedID = "NID";
           Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "NID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          // etID.setText("NID");
           break;
       case R.id.uPassport:
           if (checked)
               selectedID = "Passport";
           Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Passport", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          // etID.setText("Passport");
           break;

       case R.id.uLicense:
           if (checked)
               selectedID = "Driving License";
           Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Driving License", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // etID.setText("Driving License");
           break;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Database part:

   ```
   StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
           new Response.Listener<String>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(String response) {
                   Toast.makeText(Registration.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           },
           new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   Toast.makeText(Registration.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }){
       @Override
       protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
           Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
           params.put(KEY_NAME, name);
           params.put(KEY_EMAIL,email);
           params.put(KEY_PHONE, phoneNumber);
           params.put(KEY_DOB,dob);
           params.put(KEY_GENDER,Gender);
           params.put(KEY_PROFESSION, prof);
           params.put(KEY_ID,id);
           params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
           params.put(KEY_REPASSWORD, repassword);
           params.put(KEY_PIN,pin);
           params.put(KEY_PRESENTADDRESS,presentAddress);
           params.put(KEY_PRESENTDIVISION, prDivision);
           params.put(KEY_PRESENTDISTRICT,prDistrict);
           params.put(KEY_PRESENTTHANA,prThana);
           params.put(KEY_PERMANENTADDRESS,permanentAddress);
           params.put(KEY_PERMANENTDIVISION,perDivision);
           params.put(KEY_PERMANENTDISTRICT, perDistrict);
           params.put(KEY_PERMANENTTHANA, perThana);
           return params;
       }

   };

   RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
   requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
   ```

Comment: If I understand you right, I would use a TextView beside the EditText, programatically set the TextView to the selected radio btn value and then let the user use EditText as normal. You can then get both values within e.g. an onClick listener.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use EditText.seteditable(false); Property.
If you want to restrict user from writing something in editText.
Only editText's Text can be set from our java file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Here is my Radio Button code:

```
 public void RadioButtonClicked(View view) {



    String selectedID = "";

    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.uNid:
            if (checked)
                selectedID = "NID";
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "NID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            etID.setText("n ");
            Selection.setSelection(etID.getText(), etID.getText().length());
            etID.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                          int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                              int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (!s.toString().startsWith("n ")) {
                        etID.setText("n ");
                        Selection.setSelection(etID.getText(), etID
                                .getText().length());

                    }

                }

            });
           // etID.setText("NID");
            break;
        case R.id.uPassport:
            if (checked)
                selectedID = "Passport";
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Passport", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // etID.setText("Passport");
            etID.setText("p ");
            Selection.setSelection(etID.getText(), etID.getText().length());
            etID.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                          int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                              int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (!s.toString().startsWith("p ")) {
                        etID.setText("p ");
                        Selection.setSelection(etID.getText(), etID
                                .getText().length());

                    }

                }

            });
            break;

        case R.id.uLicense:
            if (checked)
                selectedID = "Driving License";
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Driving License", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // etID.setText("Driving License");
            etID.setText("d ");
            Selection.setSelection(etID.getText(), etID.getText().length());
            etID.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                          int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                              int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (!s.toString().startsWith("d ")) {
                        etID.setText("d ");
                        Selection.setSelection(etID.getText(), etID
                                .getText().length());

                    }

                }

            });
            break;
    }
}
```